# Serverless/Cloudformation resource that depends on the existence of another resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm trying to use the Serverless Framework to deploy a **Kinesis Firehose** that outputs to an **ElasticSearch** domain.

Since the Firehose needs the ES domain to already exist before it can be created, I am running into this error:

> An error occurred: MyFirehoseStream - Domain
>   arn:aws:es:us-east-1:1234567890:domain/my-elastic-search is still
>   being created.

Is there a way to make the Firehose creation wait until after the ES domain creation is complete?

---

Just in case its helpful, here are the relevant parts of my `serverless.yml` file:

*fyi, I'm using the `serverless-pseudo-parameters` plugin to use `#{AWS::Region}` and `#{AWS::AccountId}`*

```
resources:
  Resources:
    MyFirehoseStream:
      Type: "AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream"
      Properties:
        DeliveryStreamName: "MyFirehoseStream"
        DeliveryStreamType: "DirectPut"
        ElasticsearchDestinationConfiguration:
          BufferingHints:
            IntervalInSeconds: 300
            SizeInMBs: 5
          DomainARN:  "arn:aws:es:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:domain/my-elastic-search"
          IndexName: "myindex"
          IndexRotationPeriod: "NoRotation"
          RetryOptions:
            DurationInSeconds: 300
          RoleARN: { "Fn::GetAtt": ["FirehoseBackupBucketRole", "Arn" ] }
          S3BackupMode: "FailedDocumentsOnly"
          S3Configuration:
            BucketARN: { "Fn::GetAtt": ["FirehoseBackupBucket", "Arn" ] }
            BufferingHints:
              IntervalInSeconds: 300
              SizeInMBs: 5
            CompressionFormat: "GZIP"
            RoleARN: { "Fn::GetAtt": ["FirehoseBackupBucketRole", "Arn" ] }
          TypeName: "mytype"

    MyElasticSearch:
      Type: "AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain"
      Properties:
        AccessPolicies: ${file(./iam_policies/elastic-search.json)}
        DomainName: "my-elastic-search"
        ElasticsearchVersion: 6.2
        ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
          InstanceCount: "1"
          InstanceType: "t2.small.elasticsearch"
        EBSOptions:
          EBSEnabled: true
          Iops: 0
          VolumeSize: 10
          VolumeType: "gp2"
```

**UPDATE:**

I have this fixed now, so in case the specifics are helpful for anyone:

I changed the `DomainARN` property to `{ "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyElasticSearch", "DomainArn" ] }`.

The reason I was originally generating the ARN dynamically was because with `"Fn::GetAtt"` I originally tried to use just `Arn` instead of `DomainArn`, which didn't work. Coincidentally though, `DomainArn` has been deprecated in the latest version, so if you are using the latest version, `Arn` actually would be correct.

Comment: Please post your answer as an actual answer rather than as a question edit; Stack Overflow explicitly supports self-answered questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudformation resources support the `DependsOn` attribute.

`resources:
  Resources:
    MyFirehoseStream:
      Type: "AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream"
      DependsOn: MyElasticSearch`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be correct, but I want to point out that in my case I didn't actually need `DependsOn`. In the docs you linked to, it explains "implicit dependencies", which ended up working for me. I just needed to reference the other resource's ARN.